# mysql check time between other times

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm doing some work on a scheduler program. One of the functions is inserting tv programmes into a scheduler. On the server side this works by sending a programme id with a requested start time, i.e. 'insert programme id 123 into the schedule at 10:49 on 17-09-2012'. But the programmes have to be inserted into blocks, i.e. cultural programmes from 10pm to 12pm. So before an insert we need to check a block exists, with this piece of sql

```
SELECT t1.schedblockid, t1.blockname,
  t1.blockstart, t1.blockend, t2.scheduledate
FROM scheduleblocks t1, schedule t2
WHERE t1.schedblockid = t2.scheduleblock 
  AND t2.scheduledate = '$_GET[scheddate]'
AND '$_GET[schedtime]' >= blockstart 
AND '$_GET[schedtime]' <= blockend
```

Its simple and works, in the example above it checks that a block exists in the schedule for 17-09-2012 in which 10.49 can fit. The problem we now have is that we are trying to introduce cross day blocks, e.g. a block from 11pm to 2am. But with the sql code above it wont find the slot 23:00-02:00 when searching for time 23:51 for example.

heres the table definitions.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schedule` (
  `scheduleid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `scheduledate` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `scheduleblock` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`scheduleid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scheduleblocks` (
  `schedblockid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blockname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `blockstart` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `blockend` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `linked` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schedblockid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=44 ;
```

the tables just use varchars rather than built in date time types, and i guess thats what we need to change, but not sure how/where? Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change the table structure to:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `schedule` (
  `scheduleid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `scheduledate` DATE NOT NULL,
  `scheduleblock` TIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`scheduleid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=43 ;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `scheduleblocks` (
  `schedblockid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `blockname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `blockstart` TIME NOT NULL,
  `blockend` TIME NOT NULL,
  `linked` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`schedblockid`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=44 ;
```

You would need to `ALTER` your table if you are not starting from scratch:

```
ALTER TABLE schedule CHANGE COLUMN `scheduledate` `scheduledate` DATE NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE schedule CHANGE COLUMN `scheduleblock` `scheduleblock` TIME NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE scheduleblocks CHANGE COLUMN `blockstart` `blockstart` TIME NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE scheduleblocks CHANGE COLUMN `blockend` `blockend` TIME NOT NULL;
```